# Hartshorne Remark 1.4.6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In remark 1.4.6 the author says 'Any finitely generated $k$ algebra $B$ which is a domain is the affine coordinate ring of some affine variety'.

Since the domain $B$ is a finitely generated $k$ algebra, so, $B\cong \frac{k[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n]}{I}$, where $I$ is a prime ideal of the polynomial ring. If we take $Y=Z(I)$ then the coordinate ring of $Y$ is isomorphic to $B$. My question is how do I find an affine variety whose coordinate ring is **equal** to $B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not going to find one. Literal equality is something you can never really prove in algebra, because the underlying set of an algebraic structure could really be *anything*. You should read the "is" in the sentence 'Any finitely generated $k$ algebra $B$ which is a domain is the affine coordinate ring of some affine variety' as "is (up to isomorphism)".